# How to assign/get value to ballerina object?

Tags: ballerina

If we created ballerina [object](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/objects.html). What is the best way to assign & retrieve values of the object ? Any doc to refer it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can access public variables directly. No need to write mutables(getters/setters) for them.

You need to write your own mutators(getters/setters) for the private variables. Heres how you can write getters and setters - https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/object-member-functions.html